# Does FUSE ESB support RabbitMQ?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rabbitmq, fuseesb, jbossfuse

I am making one rails application which is integreted with RabbiMQ.
I want to integrate [Fuse ESB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FUSE_ESB) in my application, but still after google I am not confirmed that RabbitMQ supports to Fuse ESB or not.

Can anybody tell me that RabbitMQ supports Fuse ESB or not?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

FUSE ESB contains a messaging infrastructure based on the JMS technology of [Apache ActiveMQ](http://fusesource.com/products/enterprise-activemq/). ActiveMQ is [not interoperable](http://activemq.apache.org/amqp.html) out-of-the-box with AMQP systems like RabbitMQ.

However, Apache Camel (also part of FUSE) [supports AMQP](http://camel.apache.org/amqp.html) via the client API of the [Apache Qpid](http://qpid.apache.org/) project. Since both Qpid and RabbitMQ implement the [AMQP messaging standard](http://www.amqp.org/), you may be able to communicate with a RabbitMQ broker from a Qpid client. There are some potential issues and solutions associated with this approach [outlined here](http://www.rabbitmq.com/interoperability.html).

Comment: I tried this but I couldn't get Camel/Qpid working with RabbitMQ at all. I ended up doing it via Spring's AMQP Module and a component I found on Github. I wrote up a blog post on it [here](http://arthur.gonigberg.com/2012/02/11/camel-rabbitmq/) with more details.